# Parse String to most appropriate type automatically

Tags: rust

How to parse some string to most appropriate type?

I know there is `.parse::<>()` method, but you need to specify type in advance like this:

```
fn main() {
    let val = String::from("54");
    assert_eq!(val.parse::<i32>().unwrap(), 54i32);
    
    let val = String::from("3.14159");
    assert_eq!(val.parse::<f32>().unwrap(), 3.14159f32);
    
    let val = String::from("Hello!");
    assert_eq!(val.parse::<String>().unwrap(), "Hello!".to_string());
}
```

But I need something like this:

```
fn main() {
    let val = String::from("54");
    assert_eq!(val.generic_parse().unwrap(), 54i32); // or 54i16 or 54 u32 or etc ...
    
    let val = String::from("3.14159");
    assert_eq!(val.generic_parse().unwrap(), 3.14159f32);
    
    let val = String::from("Hello!");
    assert_eq!(val.generic_parse().unwrap(), "Hello!".to_string());
}
```

Is there an appropriate crate for something like this? I don't want to re-invent the wheel for the umpteenth time.

**EDIT**

This is what I actually want to do:

```
struct MyStruct<T> {
    generic_val: T,
}

fn main() {
    let val = String::from("54");
    let b = MyStruct {generic_val: val.parse().unwrap()};
    
    let val = String::from("3.14159");
    let b = MyStruct {generic_val: val.parse().unwrap()};
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `MyStruct<T>`
 --> src/main.rs:7:13
  |
7 |     let b = MyStruct {generic_val: val.parse().unwrap()};
  |         -   ^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the struct `MyStruct`
  |         |
  |         consider giving `b` the explicit type `MyStruct<T>`, where the type parameter `T` is specified
```

Comment: The problem here is `assert_eq!` not `parse`. The Rust compiler is capable of figuring out what type parameter `parse` should take without you telling it. The problem is you have to tell it, and all `assert_eq!` requires is that the types of its arguments be comparable with `==`, not that they be the same. So is this exactly how you're using it, or if I suggest a fix that focuses on `assert_eq!` will you say that doesn't work in your real code and you need something different?

Comment: Ah, I just used `assert_eq!` as example. In real code, `val` from this example will be copied to a generic in a struct. `let a = MyStruct {generic_val: val.copy(), ...etc` or something like that

Comment: Ok, so the question becomes: why can't the compiler figure out the type argument to `MyStruct`? It's [certainly possible](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1ad19124dbe2a97c7e7aacfbc1b17021) to defer the choice of `T` until well after creating `MyStruct<T>`. Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: Added in main question.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible. You have to tell Rust in one way or another what type you are expecting to parse; you can't just say "parse this as *something* and tell me what it is".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to base things on the right Enum type and implement `FromStr` for it. Like this.

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
enum Val {
    Isize(isize),
    F64(f64),
}

impl core::str::FromStr for Val {
    type Err = & 'static str;
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match (s.parse::<isize>(), s.parse::<f64>()) {
            (Ok(i),_) => Ok(Val::Isize(i)),
            (Err(_), Ok(f)) => Ok(Val::F64(f)),
            (Err(_), Err(_)) => Err("neither parser worked"),
        }
    }
}

 fn main() {
    assert_eq!("34".parse(), Ok(Val::Isize(34)));
    assert_eq!("12.3".parse(), Ok(Val::F64(12.3)));
    assert!("wrong".parse::<Val>().is_err());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rust is a statically typed language. This means that the compiler needs to know the type of variables *at compile time*. There are three ways things can go from there:

- If your strings are known at compile-time, then you might as well replace them with literal values in your code (eg. `"54"` → `54`).
- If you have some other way of knowing at compile time what type a given string should parse to, then you can specify the appropriate type when parsing the string: `let a = "54".parse::<i32>().unwrap()`
- If your strings are only known at run-time and you want to autodetect the type, then you need to use some kind of enumerated value that will store the type alongside the value in your program:

```
use std::str::FromStr;
enum Value {
    I32 (i32),
    F32 (f32),
    String (String),
}

impl Value {
    fn new (s: &str) -> Value {
        if let Ok (v) = s.parse::<i32>() {
            Value::I32 (v)
        } else if let Ok (v) = s.parse::<f32>() {
            Value::F32 (v)
        } else {
            Value::String (s.into())
        }
    }
}
```

That way, the rest of your code will have a way of knowing what type was detected and to adjust its processing accordingly.